# Why this notation for the Lexer production in antlr?

Tags: antlr

In the following SQL lexer:

- https://github.com/tshprecher/antlr_psql/blob/master/antlr4/PostgreSQLLexer.g4

It defines `true` as:

```
TRUE                                 : T R U E;
```

Why the capitals spaced out like that instead of just `TRUE: 'TRUE'` ? What's the reasoning for that notation? Does `T` refer to another production or something and that's why it's spelled like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These single letters are (fragment) lexer rules too. Check the grammar out! This way you can define case-insensitive keywords. This was the usual approach for case-insensitivity until this was built into ANTLR4 in version 4.10.

Comment: thanks, how would this be done in ANTLR v4.10?

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-options).